# Sitecore Custom Rules

Tags: c#, sitecore

I have a custom rule in Sitecore:

```
where person's status is [condition,Tree,root=/sitecore/content/Home/PersonStates, specified state]
```

I want to replace the hard coded path with one that points to any folder that has it's template id matching the one I specified. This is because the author will create these values (of a specific template in the root folder).

I have tried this and it does not work:

```
where person's status is [condition,Tree,root=query:/sitecore/content/Common/Categories/*[@@templateid='{3B0461BF-9ABC-4AF1-B937-C8D225FC2313}'], specified state]
```

Furthermore, I need to restrict some of these values based on properties that these items would have.
Eg: The author adds 5 states. I need only those states which have the active flag set to true.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box the Tree Macro does not support this, the solution is to create a custom Macro that allows a query to be executed. In order to do this you will have to implement IRuleMacro and implement your logic. Make sure to URL encode your query. Also note that the macro does not have any context when called, so you will have to implement this yourself. An example of this can be found [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8312/custom-sitecore-rule-define-query-for-parameter-item)